# In Laravel, layouts/template for data

Tags: php, laravel, view, render

I'm new to laravel, and i'm a bit lost. I search around google before asking and I didnt find about this (probably because I dont know the right terms to ask for).

I have this code

```
$query=DB::Table("users")->select("*");

echo "<table>";
foreach($query->cursor() as $o)
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><td>$o->UserId</td><td>$o->Name</td><tr>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I would like to know if there is something (a feature, class or whaterever it is called) in laravel to abstract more from the code

The idea would be to have the html stuff in another file (for example a view)

```
<tr><td>{{$o->id}}</td><td>{{$o->username}}</td></tr>
```

and call from my code with something like

```
foreach($query->cursor() as $o)
{   
    RenderView("dataview",$o);
}
```

or something like that.

I know that i have described a function :P, but my question is ,... are Laravel blade templates only for the whole pages, or can be they used to render repeated portions of the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view on resources/views/partials/item.blade.php

from controller if you need the view

```
$html = view('partials.item')->render();
```

from blade template

```
// your actual blade view
$query=DB::Table("users")->select("*");

<table>
@foreach($query->cursor() as $o)
   @include('partials.item', ['o' => $o])
@endforeach
</table>
```

```
// partials.item
<tr>
   <td> {{ $o->UserId }}</td>
   <td> {{ $o->Name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: let me try it but probably what I needed

Comment: can you elavorate the answer a bit more, what about the file partials.item, how do I get the stuff there?

Comment: From what file are you doing foreach()?

Comment: I have checked, it worsks and it is easy, just a new view and you can use the variables passed directly.

Comment: albert it is a database cursor

Comment: if you mean from what php it is a view

Comment: try this new approach. use blade templating for a better readability,